# Knockout SPA using components

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, components, web-component, r.js

I create rich client application using Knockout.js, require.js and components.

I load components on demand (first time they load from server and second time from cache).
Each component consits of two parts. "JS" part, and "HTML" view part.
For loading html part I use require.js text plugin.

I know, that i can use r.js (http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) for combining scripts together into build layer.

But I have a question 
Is it possible to combine js and html files (because each component is js and html pair)?

I think it possible, but not sure.

(or maybee it is possible to combine only js , and load html views on demand)

Comment: Have a look at http://durandaljs.com/ which uses knockoutjs, requirejs and it is based on the premise of a ViewModel (js) and View (html)

Comment: ko.components.register('like-or-dislike', {
    viewModel: { require: 'files/component-like-widget' },
    template: { require: 'text!files/component-like-widget.html' }
});

isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

As someone has mentioned in the comments, you have described what durandal gives you almost exactly.

There is minimal set up, (in fact you can just use the [skeleton](http://durandaljs.com/get-started.html) or [mimosa](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Mimosa.html) ) and once done it uses convention to pair up views to viewmodels.

You can also create [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) via knockout or use the built in durandal binding "[compose](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition.html)" to keep things small and reusable.